# How can I edit the setup.xml for Netlogo programatically?

Tags: r, xml, package, netlogo

I have created a simulation in NetLogo and I want to run multiple experiments on a Linux cluster. I need to replace the filepath in a setup xml file.

```
<enumeratedValueSet variable="str_critterpath">
  <value value="&quot;C:/Users/jorche/OneDrive - University of Leeds/Analysis/SimpleIBM/netlogo/critters.csv&quot;"/>
</enumeratedValueSet>
```

This is a new file created in an R script which creates different csv inputs for NetLogo to use. I am going to set single runs going using the system() command within the R script.

Here is the my R script so far with some hash marks denoting where I need to make a copy of the xml file with a different path in. I may want to change other variables at a later stage.

```
library(gtools)

CreatCritterCSV = function(Run, NoCritters){
  x <- 1:21
  for (i in 1:10){
    print(i)
    aperm =  t(as.matrix(permute(x), nrow =1, ncol=21))
    if(i ==1){
      df = data.frame(aperm)
    }else{
      df[i,] = aperm
    }
  }
  filename = paste("critters", Run, ".csv", sep = "")
  write.table(df, file = filename,row.names=FALSE, na="",col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
  return(filename)
}


args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
rnorm(RunNo=as.numeric(args[1]), NumberCritters=as.numeric(args[2]))

csvInput = CreatCritterCSV(RunNo, NumberCritters)

InSetupfile = "setup.xml"
#Replace the filepath to critters.csv
#
#
#
#

setupfile = paste("setup", RunNo, ".xml", sep = "")

NetLogoCommand = paste("/home/users/zabados/NetLogo/netlogo-headless.sh --model '/home/users/zabados/Ran.nlogo' --setup-file",  setupfile, "--experiment experiment --table RanTest.csv", sep = " ")

system(NetLogoCommand)
```

The xml setup file is thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE experiments SYSTEM "behaviorspace.dtd">
<experiments>
  <experiment name="experiment" repetitions="1" runMetricsEveryStep="false">
    <setup>setup</setup>
    <go>go</go>
    <exitCondition>StoppingStable</exitCondition>
    <metric>saveOutSingles</metric>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DiffIntraDen">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DiffWalk">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="maxReproRate">
      <value value="0.05"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="NumberZetas">
      <value value="0"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="interdensity">
      <value value="1"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="ExtraMort">
      <value value="0.5"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DiffMaxRepro">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="intraRadius">
      <value value="0"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DiffSpeeds">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="GenSpec">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DiffInterDen">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DiffSpdCoe">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DiffStartNum">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="interRadius">
      <value value="5"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="PopGrowExp">
      <value value="0.5"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="SameSpeed">
      <value value="5"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="logiMidpoint">
      <value value="11"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="Imortal_infert">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DisplaySpecies">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DripFeedRate">
      <value value="0"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="StartingExp">
      <value value="10"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DiffExtraMort">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="SimpleDensity">
      <value value="true"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="str_critterpath">
      <value value="&quot;C:/Users/jorche/OneDrive - University of Leeds/Analysis/SimpleIBM/netlogo/critters.csv&quot;"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="intradensity">
      <value value="2"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="max_age">
      <value value="3"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="WalkType">
      <value value="&quot;Logistic&quot;"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DiffAge">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DripFeedNumber">
      <value value="1"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="SpeciesPresenceCutOff">
      <value value="1"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="SpeedCoef">
      <value value="0.4"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="DiffPopGrExp">
      <value value="false"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="walk_exp">
      <value value="0.6"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="CRW_multi">
      <value value="90"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="StartingEachSpecies">
      <value value="30"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="PrefMoveExp">
      <value value="0.5"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
    <enumeratedValueSet variable="MemLen">
      <value value="2000"/>
    </enumeratedValueSet>
  </experiment>
</experiments>
```

Any help would be greatly recieved. I've tried to gsub the xml as though it was a txt file with no joy and to parse the xml file using the package r xml. Not getting anywhere fast.

Cheers.

Comment: So the only thing you need to modify in your xml file is the filepath? Are you manually putting in the new filepath to the critters.csv?

Comment: At the moment this was the thing I needed to change. I may need to change other things in future runs, but I can now modify your function below if needs be to take a different path_node_index string. The script above generates a csv file automatically, so it needs to be automatically added to the xml file. With your help I now have a working script. Thanks Jordan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to modify the filepath value in your xml file, try this function:

```
modify_xml_filepath <- function(original_xml, 
                                new_filepath = "", 
                                new_experiment_name = "new_experiment.xml") {
    # Parse the original file
    parsed <- read_xml(original_xml)
    nodeset <- xml_children(xml_children(parsed)[[1]])

    # Get the node that stores the current path
    path_node_index <- which(xml_attrs(nodeset) == "str_critterpath")

    # Save the current value for removal
    to_remove <- xml_children(nodeset[[path_node_index]])

    # Add the new filepath, then remove the old one
    xml_add_child(nodeset[[path_node_index]], "value", "value" = new_filepath)
    xml_remove(to_remove)

    # Write out the modified file
    write_xml(parsed, new_experiment_name)
}
```

Called like this:

```
modify_xml_filepath(original_xml = "example_experiment.xml", 
                    new_filepath = "new_filepath_here",
                    new_experiment_name = "new_output.xml"
                    )
```

Outputs a new xml file for me called "new_output.xml", where the `str_critterpath` is modified to:

```
<enumeratedValueSet variable="str_critterpath">
  <value value="new_filepath"/>
</enumeratedValueSet>
```

**Edit:** To include quotations in the output xml file (as in the original), add this line above the first `xml_add_child(...` line:

```
new_filepath = paste("\"", new_filepath, "\"", sep = "")
```

New filepath node will now look like:

```
<enumeratedValueSet variable="str_critterpath">
  <value value="&quot;new_filepath_here&quot;"/>
</enumeratedValueSet>
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. This is the first question I have asked after having been a reader for many years and spending hours sometimes days finding solutions myself.

Your answer has saved me loads of time and is exactly what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: @JordanChetcuti - Glad it got you on the right track, nice work with the modification! Have a look at my edit for a possible alternative to your solution to the quotation issue, but I may be off the mark if you can't have the `quot` as in your original filepath.

Comment: That mod works a treat and is much tidier.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else trying to get this solution to work with Netlogo and a computer cluster, I had to make a minor tweak to Luke C's solution. This is because the xml file needs " in it around the filepath. I tried to simply add them to the filepath and ended up with "&amp"quot; which caused problems. I therefore did some substitutions. Its less pretty, but now working on the cluster.

```
modify_xml_filepath <- function(original_xml, 
                                new_filepath = "", 
                                new_experiment_name = "new_experiment.xml") {
  # Parse the original file
  parsed <- read_xml(original_xml)
  nodeset <- xml_children(xml_children(parsed)[[1]])

  # Get the node that stores the current path
  path_node_index <- which(xml_attrs(nodeset) == "str_critterpath")

  # Save the current value for removal
  to_remove <- xml_children(nodeset[[path_node_index]])


  New = gsub("C:/Users/jorche/OneDrive - University of Leeds/Analysis/SimpleIBM/netlogo/critters.csv", new_filepath, to_remove)
  New = sub("<", "", New)
  New = sub("/>", "", New)
  # Add the new filepath, then remove the old one
  #xml_add_child(nodeset[[path_node_index]], "value", "value" = new_filepath)
  xml_add_child(nodeset[[path_node_index]], New)
  xml_remove(to_remove)

  # Write out the modified file
  write_xml(parsed, new_experiment_name)
}
```

Comment: Luke C's modification is much tidier and does the job.